# Boolean-Algebraic computation

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I am having trouble understanding a certain computation in a proof I am reading.

Suppose $I$ is an ideal in some Boolean algebra. And suppose we have $¬a_0 =a\vee b$ for some $a\leq a_0$ and $b\in I$.

Then $¬a_0 =¬a_0\land ¬a_0 =(a\vee b)\land ¬a_0 =b$.

I am aware of the basic algebraic properties of Boolean algebras, but **I just can't see how $(a\vee b)\land ¬a_0 =b$.** Could someone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works:

$(a \vee b) \wedge \neg a_0 = (\neg a_0 \wedge a) \vee (\neg a_0 \wedge b) =  \neg a_0 \wedge b =(a \vee b) \wedge b  =  b.$

For the second equality, note that $\neg a \wedge \neg a_0 = \neg(a \vee a_0) = \neg a_0$, using $a \leq a_0$. Then,

$$\neg a_0 \wedge a = (\neg a \wedge \neg a_0) \wedge a = 0.$$

This is just spelling everything out very formally, but to eyeball these sorts of calculations it helps to think of everything as set operations ($\wedge = \cap$, $\leq = \subseteq$, etc.) or as logical connectives with $\leq$ as logical implication.

Comment: It doesn't matter. But how do you get the middle equality $(\neg a_0 \land a)\vee (\neg a_0\land b)=\neg a_0\land b$?

Comment: not A and A, is the entire set. Thus in a union it can be omitted.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Does the edit help?

Comment: @JahKnows I don't think that's right (if I understand you correctly). $\neg a_0 \wedge a = 0$ (see the edit), and $0 \vee x  = x$. If you want to think about this as a Boolean algebra of sets, then "not A and A" is the _empty set_. The union of "the entire set" with any other set is the entire set.

Comment: my mistake. Indeed the union of not A and A is null. You cannot both be in A and not in A.

Comment: @aduh Yes, great explantation. Thanks!