# Showing that an ideal generated by $M\cup \{b\}$ is proper (boolean algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ideals, boolean-algebra

Suppose $B$ is a boolean algebra and $M$ is an ideal. Suppose $b\in B$ and $\neg b\notin M$. Then I want to show that the ideal $I$ generated by $M\cup \{b\}$ is proper.

Note that my definition of an ideal generated by some set $S$ is the intersection of all ideals containing $S$.

I know that an ideal is improper if and only if it contains $1$ but am still unsure of how to proceed.

I have tried to suppose otherwise and derive the contradiction that $\neg b\in M$. I realize that if $I$ is improper, then the only ideal containing $M\cup \{b\}$ is $B$.

But I have not had success and would appreciate if someone could explain a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to characterize the ideal $I$ generated by $M \cup \{b\}$ as follows:

$$ I = \{\, b_0 \vee a : b_0 \leq b \text{ and } a \in M \,\} \enspace. $$

This result is proved in, say, Givant and Halmos, *Introduction to Boolean Algebras*, Chapter 18.

You can then prove that $\neg b \not\in I$ by noting that $\neg b \in I$ implies the existence of $b_0 \leq b$ and $a \in M$ such that

$$ \neg b = b_0 \vee a \enspace. $$

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2302066/123852) you find a proof that this can only be if $\neg b = a$, contradicting the assumption that $\neg b \not\in M$.

Since ideals are *down sets*, $I = B$ implies $\neg b \in I$; since $\neg b \not\in I$, it must be $I \neq B$.